# Hosting a Custom Activity on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, custom-activity, cloudpagesurl

I'm creating a Custom Activity and I would like to try to host its files directly on Marketing Cloud, let's say, on Web Studio using CloudPages. As far as I understand, Cloudpages does not expose the file extension for each Cloudpage. In other words, I can't have an index.html; instead, as soon as I create the Cloudpage with the proper code, the URL Marketing cloud will generate will be:

```
https://fe321171716405xxx.pub.s11.sfmc-content.com/XxxXn3snk3e
```

...and so on for the other required files. Is there something I can do to host the file structure for a custom activity on Marketing Cloud?

Comment: what is your custom activity doing that can't be handle by one of the OOTB activities?

Comment: @EazyE I'm testing it, I had no clue about custom activities and now that I finally got it working, I would like to see if it is possible to Marketing Cloud to host its files.